# Microsoft Bot Framework Emulator not installing - Error with dfsvc.exe

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, bots, clickonce

Trying to install the Microsoft Bot Framework Emulator on Windows 10 x64, ClickOnce is crashing and Event Log is showing the following error:

```
Faulting application name: dfsvc.exe, version: 4.6.1038.0, time stamp: 0x5615c2b6

Faulting module name: kaijuu64.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x50153b50

Exception code: 0xc0000005

Fault offset: 0x0000000000018fab

Faulting process ID: 0x3120

Faulting application start time: 0x01d18b5df8bc3fb6

Faulting application path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\dfsvc.exe

Faulting module path: C:\Users\jmk\Downloads\bsnes_v091-64bit\bsnes_v091-64bit\kaijuu64.dll

Report ID: c616cc80-ba0a-4ba1-a6da-af159ea3013f

Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Tried running as Administrator, restarting my machine, no luck.

Could this be a bug with the installer itself?

Comment: what is this kaijuu64.dll? this causes the crash

Comment: Do you meet the system requirements.  I have no doubt the version of .NET Framework it requires is 4.6.x ( the current version ) but you apparently have `4.0.30319` installed

Comment: @Ramhound I'm running Visual Studio 2015, Update 2 (released yesterday) on Windows 10 so I'm fairly sure I do!

Comment: Well..."Faulting application path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\dfsvc.exe" just indicates something different.  RTM of Update 2?

Comment: 4.0.30319 is the directory for every 4.x version of the .net framework, each one is an in-place upgrade of the previous

Comment: again, the  kaijuu64.dll causes the crash. What is it?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I think it's a part of the .net framework

Comment: no, it is inside your download folder. Do a rightclick on the file, select properties and look for the product name/vendor name